Always show the full file dialog when moving a file
I like to organise my files into folders, and because of this I'm not a fan of the drop-down list that appears by default when you save a file on MacOS. I usually want to put the file in a specific folder, which means I usually have to scroll to the bottom of the drop down list and click "other" to get to the full save dialog.
I was able to fix that problem using the following commands in Terminal, from this page:
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSNavPanelExpandedStateForSaveMode -bool true
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSNavPanelExpandedStateForSaveMode2 -bool true

These commands cause the full save file dialog to appear straight away when saving a file, skipping the drop-down list.
However, this only affects the Save As dialog and not the Move To dialog. So if I download a file, open it in Preview, and then try to move it into a folder, I still get the drop down list.
What I would like is to skip the drop down list in that case as well. Is it possible?

Not directly the same thing, but do you know that you can move the file by dragging the icon in the window title from Preview into any Finder location?

@nohillside true, but I usually find "move to" more convenient, as I don't always have the folder open in Finder

I don't think you'll find anything. That Move To dialog looks extremely "custom" and non-standard. Possibly contrary to Apple's own Interface Guidelines (like so much in Preview)..

@benwiggy is right; that 'Move To' dialog doesn't have the capacity to expand. Your best bet might be to create a custom service in Automator that you can access from the Services menu.  do you know how to do that?

@TedWrigley I don't know how to do that. But the "move to" dialog is identical to the "save as" dialog, isn't it? So surely there must be a default that affects it in the analogous way?

It's not just a Preview issue - I just checked and the "move to" dialog is the same in Keynote, so I'm pretty sure it's a MacOS thing.

I stand corrected: it does seem to be in other apps too. (I've never used it! If I want to move something, I do it in the Finder.) Even so, there will only be a defaults write key option that changes the behaviour if the developers have gone to the trouble to add one.

In my version of Preview (OS Sonoma) the 'Move To' dialog is a simple pane with one pulldown button, no bells or whistles. Same in Pages. I think it's meant to move things to a short list of predetermined locations (thought I'd have to play with it to figure out how to add a predetermined location). The 'Save As' document (even in its collapsed form) has multiple elements. 'Move To' is a different dialog box entirely, with nothing to expand.

I've got a busy day, but this evening I'll try to whip up a service that will work.

@TedWrigley I think your 'Move To' dialog is probably the same as mine. The last item in that drop-down should be "Other...", which takes you to a good old fashioned file selection dialog - it's that stage I'm hoping to get to straight away, without needing to select "Other...".

(In some version of MacOS the "save as" dialog was the same as the "move to" one, but maybe it's different now, I don't know because I have it set to always expand.)

Although the terminal defaults likely do the same thing, there is no need for these.  Directly to the right of the folder drop-down list is a down arrow icon.  Clicking that icon switches to a full Finder-like navigation view that will remain the default for future save dialogs.
